# Share file between 2 instances

Tags: mysql, bucket

I have 2 GC Debian instances. 1 is configured as LAMP, and other is just a FILE server (No http/https configured, No static IP).
What is the best way for me to upload file from FILE server to LAMP server (Ultimately I will insert data from the file to MySQL table)

I researched for awhile now, and ended up setting a bucket and mounted disks /home/username/shared on both servers. (FULL storage permissions on both servers)

I was able to see the file with bytes on FILE server, but when I looked at the LAMP server, I see the file name, but its zero bytes.

So this did not work.

What are my other options to get this file to LAMP server?

Is there a way to have mysql command inserting data from my FILE server to LAMP server? Is it secure?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming file server is running Linux as well, can you SSH between the two systems? If yes, https://www.linux.com/learn/intro-to-linux/2017/2/how-securely-transfer-files-between-servers-scp will help you use SSH/SCP to transfer files. rsync is another option: https://www.atlantic.net/hipaa-compliant-cloud-storage/how-to-use-rsync-copy-sync-files-servers/

Comment: Just to clarify, on your LAMP server, when looking at the filesystem (Not through apache/php) are you able to see the file completely?

Comment: Using SSH and looking at it with ls -la command it shows zero bytes. And FILE server also now shows 0 bytes. FILE server has new .swp file with some bytes on it... tried to restart LAMP server, but it tells me not enough resources to start, try again later. So my LAMP is currently down :(

Comment: Both are Debian stretch. Im trying to add SSH between servers. I tried ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/[KEY_FILENAME] -C [USERNAME] and then going to LAMP instance and copying .pub file content to ssh section. It gives me Permission denied (publickey). when trying to connect. I have my FILE username added as a -C (comment), after reading GC needs this. Plz gimme a link how to set this up, or explain, why this is not working. much appreciated. thx